# Is there something like DefaultOutputCellStyle?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, cells, customization, output

Is there any option to set so that e.g. `"Input"` cell will produce output in e.g. `"Custom"` style cell as opposed to `"Output"`?

Or do I have use `CellEpilog`/`CellDynamicExpression` to change generated `"Output"` cell?

Comment: From linked topic: `"GeneratedCellStyles" -> {"Output" -> (* style *)}`